# Control TCP access by user

Tags: tcp, windows-server

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server in an intranet that has a TCP port open and client machines connect to from their software. Without intervening in the application to restrict the access only to selected users or selected computer names? We have dynamic IP.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to filter incoming connections by hostname using the Windows firewall?

Comment: @Hollowproc using Windows firewall or any simple addon to the machine I would like to restrict by Active Directory username ideally, but hostname (of the client) would be good too

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx